# Image processing exercise and np.array indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i try to understand an exercice found on this website:
http://scipy-lectures.org/intro/summary-exercises/answers_image_processing.html

The endpoint is to remove from a picture (sand_op) of sand viewed under microscope the grains that are smaller than 10 pixels:

```
sand_labels, sand_nb = ndimage.label(sand_op)
sand_areas = np.array(ndimage.sum(sand_op, sand_labels, np.arange(sand_labels.max()+1)))
mask = sand_areas > 100
remove_small_sand = mask[sand_labels.ravel()].reshape(sand_labels.shape)
plt.imshow(remove_small_sand)
```

My problem is about this part:

```
mask[sand_labels.ravel()]
```

where mask is a np.array of shape (155,) full of boolean
and where sand_labels is a np.array of shape (883, 1024)

I don't understand how we can index the np.array mask with a np.array flattened of shape (904192,), that is to say much larger! Why don't we have an IndexError like "..out of bounds for axis 0"?

Thanks in advance!

Gwénolé

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have access to confirm the question, but you can index an array as many times as you want, as long as your index does not fall out of bounds of the array. Here is an example to clarify it:

```
mask=np.array([True, False])
#mask[0]=True
#mask[1]=False
print(mask[[0,0,0,0,1]])
#[ True  True  True  True False]

#this will throw error because index 2 does not exist in mask and NOT because it calls elements too many times.    
print(mask[[0,0,2]])
#IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```